# Best way to implement logout in Firebase v3.0.1+? Firebase.unauth is removed after update

Tags: javascript, authentication, firebase, ecmascript-6

Using new firebase 3.0.1 which was recently published by google.

Before, we had `Firebase.unauth()` method https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/api/firebase/unauth.html

But it's old API. I can't see anything related in new API:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/node/index-all

What are your solutions? Trying to use something like:

```
Object.keys(localStorage).forEach(key => {
  if (key.indexOf('firebase') !== -1) {
    localStorage.removeItem(key);
  }
});
```

Comment: Read this: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/password-auth#next_steps

Comment: thanks @AndréKool found answer there, i will paste it here too

Answer (score 148, accepted):

catch error with callback:

```
firebase.auth().signOut().then(function() {
  // Sign-out successful.
}, function(error) {
  // An error happened.
});
```

or with .catch as Adam mentioned.

```
firebase.auth().signOut()
  .then(function() {
    // Sign-out successful.
  })
  .catch(function(error) {
    // An error happened
  });
```

Or with await and `try...catch` if inside async function

```
try {
  await firebase.auth().signOut();
  // signed out
} catch (e){
 // an error
}
```

https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/password-auth#next_steps

thanks [AndréKool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37343309/best-way-to-implement-logout-in-firebase-v3-0-1-firebase-unauth-is-removed-afte/37345095#comment62206306_37343309) for directions :-)

Comment: It uses a catch function.

Answer (score 12):

Lukas Liesis has the correct firebase signOut() method but to resolve a rejected promise, I used `.catch()` instead.

```
firebase.auth().signOut()
  .then(function() {
    // Sign-out successful.
  })
  .catch(function(error) {
    // An error happened
  });
```

Answer (score 4):

This statement logouts the user.

```
    FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();
```

Comment: and fails to take action if something wrong happens. Use `then & catch` as in accepted answer or surround by `try...catch` and catch error in catch block.